# Php array_search value of key and not a number

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$lk = array(
'About_US' => array(
    'en' => 'about-us',
    'es' => 'sobre-nosotros',
),
'Shared_Hosting' => array(
    'en' => 'website-shared-hosting',
    'es' => 'alojamiento-de-sitios',
),
```

And I need to get the name "Shared_Hosting" by this type of search

```
        $key = array_search('website-shared-hosting', array_column($lk, 'en'));
        echo $key;
```

The value of $key for me shows "1" instead of "Shared_Hosting", its because we have "0" as "About_US" and "1" as "Shared_Hosting" (i believe).

If I try to echo $key this will result in "1"
I tried for all day to get $key = "Shared_Hosting"
Tried so many ways and functions!

Maybe another function instead of array_column?

Thank you everyone for read it and help!

Comment: whats wrong with `print_r($lk[$key]);`? You got your target there already! Or what do you want?

Comment: Already tried it before, but it gives me that error:
Undefined offset: 1 in <b>/devel/index.php</b>

Comment: true, sorry, was a quick shot - and wrong.

Comment: I believe that is stop my job something like 14 hours trying this. And for sure, there is an easy solution, I maybe just didn't think in the right way!

Comment: From my point of view there won't be an easy solution, but looping through that array. But I'd be happy to learn something new...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's my easiest solution I could find, I don't think there would be a one-liner:

```
<?php

$lk = array(
'About_US' => array(
    'en' => 'about-us',
    'es' => 'sobre-nosotros',
),
'Shared_Hosting' => array(
    'en' => 'website-shared-hosting',
    'es' => 'alojamiento-de-sitios',
)
);

$foundIn = [];

forEach($lk as $key => $sub) {
    if(array_search('website-shared-hosting', $sub)) {
        $foundIn[] = $key;
    }
}

var_dump($foundIn);

// Output: array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "Shared_Hosting" }
```

Comment: It works, but... I should find it by the 'en', anyway its a good solution at this time because now I can use if in_array function! Thank you for that help!

Comment: Thank you again Jeff, with this I have solved my problem.